# Mongoose returns default value for field even when the field removed from the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a school schema like this:

```
var SchoolSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: true}
  status: { type: String, default: "active" }
});
```

Mongoose default feature works on two levels:
1) Set field value to default while saving, if the field is not present in the input.
2) While fetching, set field value to default value, if the field is not present in the saved document.

What I wish is for it to set it to default value only while saving, and when fetching a document it should return null value for status if the status property is not present in the record. Currently it returns 'active' when I remove status property from the record.

Is there a way I could do this Mongoose?

Comment: If you're setting a default value when saving, aren't you going to always get a result anyway? Or are you wiping the value in between?

Comment: Change to "notactive"

Comment: If you're changing the value to 'notactive' that's what you'd get as a result. You'll only get the default value if you actually remove the value.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the case where I wipe the property in between, or if there existed a previous record which did not have that property.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the pre-save middleware.
It would look something like this:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {   
 // Change your fields
 next() 
})
```

This code will be activated when you save your mongo document.

Mongoose also adds a `isNew` field to your object so you could extend this code to only change your fields if this is the first time the document is being save to the DB

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {   
 if (this.isNew) {
   // Change your fields
 }
 next() 
})
```

Comment: A lot of mongooses power comes from these middleware functions, so definitely take the time to read up on them.